# Can two random variables $X,Y$ be dependent and such that $E(XY)=E(X)E(Y)$?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

Can someone define independence of two random variables with this "product rule", or are there any counterexamples?

Comment: Sure there are, try X standard normal and Y=UX with U symmetric Bernoulli.

Comment: @Did, what do you mean by symmetric Bernoulli? $P(U=0) = P(U=1)$?

Comment: P(U=1)=P(U=-1)=1/2

Comment: @Did Is that a [Bernoulli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution) variable? I don't think so.

Comment: @CarlosMendoza Many people call Bernoulli what you probably call a two-points distribution.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Independence implies uncorrelation**

We say that two random variables are [uncorrelated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncorrelated_random_variables) if $E[XY]  = E[X]E[Y]$.

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent and discrete (this can also be extended to continuous random variables), then

$$p_{X,Y}(x,y) = p_X(x)p_Y(y)\qquad \forall (x,y)$$

Using this in the definition of $E[XY]$ and doing some rearrangements of terms, we have

\begin{align}
E[XY] &= \sum_x\sum_y xyp_{X,Y}(x,y)\\
&= \sum_x\sum_y xyp_X(x)p_Y(y)\\
&= \sum_x\sum_y [xp_X(x)][yp_Y(y)]\\
&= \sum_xxp_X(x)\sum_yyp_Y(y)\\
&= E[X]E[Y]
\end{align}

Therefore, if $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then they are uncorrelated.

$\\$

**Uncorrelation does not imply independence (in general)**

In general$^1$, it is false to say that if $X$ and $Y$ are uncorrelated, then they are independent. Let's see a counterexample. Let $X$ and $Y$ be random variables taking values in $\{(0,1), (1,0), (-1,0), (0,-1)\}$ with equal probability $0.25$. Then, $XY = 0$ with probability $1$, and therefore $E[XY] = 0$.

By other hand,

$\displaystyle p_X(x) = \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
\frac{1}{4} & x=-1\\
\frac{1}{2} & x=0\\
\frac{1}{4} & x=1\\
\end{array}
\right.
$ $\hspace{1cm}$ and $\hspace{1cm}$ $p_Y(y) = \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
\frac{1}{4} & y=-1\\
\frac{1}{2} & y=0\\
\frac{1}{4} & y=1\\
\end{array}
\right.
$

which implies that $E[X]=E[Y]=0$. Then, $E[XY] = E[X]E[Y]$ and the random variables are uncorrelated.

However,

$$p_X(1)p_Y(1) =  \frac{1}{4}\frac{1}{4} \neq p_{X,Y}(1,1) = 0$$

which shows that $X$ and $Y$ are not independent.

We can conclude then that independence is a *sufficient* but not a *necessary* condition for uncorrelation.

---

$^1$ The only two exceptions I am aware of are the [**jointly** Gaussian variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution) and [two Bernoulli random variables](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/74410/for-which-distributions-does-uncorrelatedness-imply-independence)...any other?

Comment: So you group terms into 2 sums because y's terms are not dependent on x's sum and vice versa please?

Comment: @Avv. I edited my answer to add two additional steps and hopefully make it clearer. In the third line, you move the factor $xp_X(x)$ out of the sum $\sum_y$ because it doesn't depend on $y$, only on $x$.

Comment: I upvoted the answer. It's very clear now. Thank you.

Comment: One more thing please. Why if $g(y) = E[X|Y=y]$ then $E[E[X|y=y]]$ is not expectation of a number but expectation of a random variable? Should not $E[X|y=y]$ be treated as a number not a random variable please so we have $E[E[X|y=y]] = E[X|Y=y]$?

Comment: @Avv, I am not sure how your question relates to the original question and my answer. Please elaborate.

Your question seems to be a new question, and you should probably ask it in a new post, but I will try to answer in the next comment....

Comment: Assuming that $X,Y \in \mathbb{R}$ (not random vectors), $E[X \mid Y]$ is a random variable and $E[X \mid Y=y]$ is a scalar. The law of iterated expectations states that $E[E[X \mid Y]] = E[X]$.